# How to split a string based on a general format of the splitting unit?

Tags: r, string

I need to split a long string. The places where the splits should be have nothing in common except the fact that they are dates followed by time. Hence, I need to split the string based on the occurrence of a specific pattern, namely `dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mm`. While I know the functions `strsplit`, and the allied string manipulators, they do not seem to help. The sample of the data is below.

```
25/06/15, 21:37 - kjadshjabsdjab
25/06/15, 21:39 - bsadhi2342/342jbjsd
25/06/15, 21:40 -hkgsad/213/1sadjaa
25/06/15, 21:41 - hsdjhakhjbk12/21s/sda:sdfjbj
25/06/15, 21:42 - jkadbsh2:/\sdsadjv
25/06/15, 21:42 -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use regex lookarounds to split

```
strsplit(str1, "(?<=[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})", perl = TRUE)
```

If we need to include the 'Date' as well

```
strsplit(str1, "(?<=[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}, [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})", perl = TRUE)
```

---

If we don't want the Date time, then

```
setdiff(strsplit(str1, "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}, [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\s*-\\s*")[[1]], "")
#[1] "kjadshjabsdjab"               "bsadhi2342/342jbjsd" 
#[3] "hkgsad/213/1sadjaa"           "hsdjhakhjbk12/21s/sda:sdfjbj" 
#[5] "jkadbsh2:/\\sdsadjv"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the regex or mutate+sub the `-` away if it's not needed:

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

lines <- readLines(textConnection('25/06/15, 21:37 - kjadshjabsdjab\n25/06/15, 21:39 - bsadhi2342/342jbjsd\n25/06/15, 21:40 -hkgsad/213/1sadjaa\n25/06/15, 21:41 - hsdjhakhjbk12/21s/sda:sdfjbj\n25/06/15, 21:42 - jkadbsh2:/\\sdsadjv\n25/06/15, 21:42 -'))

stri_match_all_regex(lines, "([[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}, [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2})(.*)") %>%
  map_df(~setNames(as.list(.[,2:3]), c("ts", "string")))
## # A tibble: 6 × 2
##                ts                          string
##             <chr>                           <chr>
## 1 25/06/15, 21:37                - kjadshjabsdjab
## 2 25/06/15, 21:39           - bsadhi2342/342jbjsd
## 3 25/06/15, 21:40             -hkgsad/213/1sadjaa
## 4 25/06/15, 21:41  - hsdjhakhjbk12/21s/sda:sdfjbj
## 5 25/06/15, 21:42           - jkadbsh2:/\\sdsadjv
## 6 25/06/15, 21:42                               -
```

Answer (score 1):

One could split at " - " and then exclude last 15 characters. The function sapply can be used to apply substr function to each item of the list:

```
> ss = "25/06/15, 21:37 - kjadshjabsdjab25/06/15, 21:39 - bsadhi2342/342jbjsd25/06/15, 21:40 - hkgsad/213/1sadjaa25/06/15, 21:41 - hsdjhakhjbk12/21s/sda:sdfjbj25/06/15, 21:42 - jkadbsh2:sdsadjv25/06/15, 21:42 -"
> 
> sapply(strsplit(ss, " - "), function(x) substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-15))
     [,1]                          
[1,] ""                            
[2,] "kjadshjabsdjab"              
[3,] "bsadhi2342/342jbjsd"         
[4,] "hkgsad/213/1sadjaa"          
[5,] "hsdjhakhjbk12/21s/sda:sdfjbj"
[6,] "jkadbsh2:sdsadjv25"
```